# why the lazy collection is loaded

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a Project entity with a oneToMany relationship with Event entity

```
public class Project {
   ....

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dossier", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Event> events;

}
```

I have a ProjectService class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProjectService {

    public List<Project> findAll() {
        return (List<Project>) projectRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And a ProjectController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/projects")
public class ProjectController {

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Project> getAllProject() {
        return projectService.findAll();
    }
}
```

In my client code I saw that the events of the projects are loaded and I don't understand why.

I expected that at the end of the transaction of the method findAll in DossierService, the entities will be detached. Obviously my entities are still attached as the events are retrieved during the jackson serialization in my controller.

Comment: what exactly are you try to ask?

Comment: I don't understand why the events are loaded while the collection is Lazy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Project.events` is by default lazy-loaded because it is a `OneToMany` relationship.

It does not mean that `Project.events` is not loaded. It means that it will be loaded as soon as `Project.getEvents()` is called.

This occurs at the JSON serialization (when `ProjectController.getAllProject()` returns its response).

In order to prevent that, there are 2 ways :

- Either you explicitly call `project.setEvents(null)` (or an empty list) on every project returned by `ProjectService`.
- Or you add a `@JsonIgnore` annotation on `Project.events`.

**EDIT**: if you are using spring-boot, an [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html) is registered by default :

> Spring web request interceptor that binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request. Intended for the "Open EntityManager in View" pattern, i.e. to allow for lazy loading in web views despite the original transactions already being completed.

You can disable this behavior by adding this line to `application.properties` :

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

With this configuration, calling the getter outside of the hibernate session will cause a `LazyInitializationException`.

Comment: I have always thought when you try to access lazy-loaded entites for the first time OUTSIDE the transaction, you would get a null

Comment: Same as @TomasKralik, why the getEvents works outside the transaction. ?

Comment: AFAIK, it depends on your ORM. With hibernate, you will get a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`. With iBatis, you might get null but I did not test.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I don't understand why I don't get a LazyInitializationException in my controller during the serialization. I expected the persistence context to be closed in my controller, obviously it's still opened after the call of the method findAll as the events collection is correctly retrieved. When does spring open and close the persistence context ? (I thought it was each time a transaction is begun and closed)

Comment: @oliv37 If you are using spring-boot, it automatically registers an `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` which binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request. If you want to prevent this behavior, you can add `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in application.properties. Then, you will get the expected `LazyInitializationException`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. An `OpenSessionInView` or `OpenEntityManagerInView` bean has been defined.   This type of bean causes the `Session` or `EntityManager`, respectively, to be opened at the time the controller is invoked and remains open until the controller's body has been serialized.

   It is typically considered acceptable behavior in demo/small applications, but it's highly frowned upon in larger more complex applications as your queries should return fully initialized entities required for your view, controller, or logic.
2. The JSON library has a hibernate addon enabled where it is capable of reattaching and hydrating the entity during the serialization process.

Otherwise, the default behavior that you expect where the `Session`/`EntityManager` has closed and the entity is detached once it's returned by the service is accurate.  The expected behavior would be a `LazyInitializationException` otherwise.

Comment: Spring-boot indeed adds an `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` by default (configurable).

Answer (score 0):

Your entities are still attached until:

- You ask the entity manager to clear the persistence context using entityManager.clear()
- You ask the entity manager to detach your entity using entityManager.detach(project) for every project.

But if you know that your events will be loaded most of the time, you should then consider using FetchType.EAGER so that everything would be fetched at once.

Comment: I expected spring to close the persitence context at the end of the transaction (after the call of findAll() in DossierService), I don't understand why the persistence context is still opened in my controller. When does spring open and close the persistence context ?